# Best practice for initializing an ArrayList field in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, initialization

What's the best practice for initializing an ArrayList field in Java (to avoid testing null value) ?

At declaration, like this :

```
private List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Or in the getter, like this :

```
public List<String> getMyList() {
    if(myList == null) {
        myList = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    return myList;
}
```

Or, in the constructor :

```
public Test(){
    myList = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

Maybe it's the same, but I am curious to know.

Comment: The first one. Lazy initialization is massively overrated, and much more likely to have thread safety issues.

Comment: @cricket_007 I edited my question for the constructor option

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first option allows you to do a

```
private final List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Thus preventing you from accidentally creating a completely new list later on; thus helping with (many, not all) multi-threading issues. In addition to that, now the compiler can help you to make sure that your field is initialized **exactly once**.

Beyond that, the second option can be seen as "lazy initialization". And in that sense: it can be seen as "optimization choice"! And from there: many people advocate on avoiding premature optimization!

You know, when you can't rely on the list being already created that can cause a lot of trouble. So even when coming from that perspective, you have another argument to prefer option 1!

Edit, regarding the compiler option: from a semantics point there option 1 and 3 are (more or less) "equal" [hint: if you find that it makes a difference in your code if you choose option1 or option3 ... that would be a good indication that your are doing something terribly wrong in your code).

Nonetheless, the one thing that can make a difference - if you have a "dependency injection" constructor, like:

```
public YourClass() { this(new ArrayList<String>); }
YourClass(List<String> incomingList) { myList = incomingList; }
```

This solution makes sense for those kinds of objects that you need to "control"; in the sense of: you require to pass mocks to your class to enable unit testing.

Long story short:

- Prefer option1, if possible: using **final**
- Use option3 if dependency injection is required
- Avoid option2 unless you have really good reasons to go for it

Comment: Option 3 also allows `final`

Comment: can you explain why use final for option 1 ?

Comment: @JavaDev Simply spoken: because you simply gain all the things that I list up there for free? Sorry, I don't get your question: I thought I did put quite some reasoning there why option1+final is the "best choice".

Comment: @Jägermeister I mean option1 is to prefer, OK I agree according to your explanation. But why is it better to use final keyword with this option ?

Comment: @JavaDev I said so to: because that prevents you from overriding the field. And the compiler tells you when you **forget** to initialize the field. Long story short: the best policy is to make **all fields final**; and you should only deviate from that rule when you have good reasons to do so. Prefer immutable objects!

Answer (score 1):

In general lazy initialization in the getter is more trouble than it's worth. If you have a serious issue where you want to minimize the memory used by the list (because you expect it to be empty for most cases), you could initialize it with an initial capacity of zero:

```
private List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(0);
```

There is no practical difference between initializing in the instance variable declaration and in the constructor, except for legibility. It's easier to make sure everything is initialized if you put the initialization on the instance declaration, with the constructor you have to match the initializations in the constructor back to the instance variables to make sure they're covered.

A lot of real world code has to work with third party libraries and frameworks. When you create a class that has to work with a library or framework like Hibernate or Spring, lazy initialization in the getter is out of the question, either because Spring took over wiring these things for you, or because the library using your class swaps out your List implementation for its own for various reasons (Hibernate will do this to implement lazy loading). So make your getters and setters as simple and direct as possible in order that they don't invalidate assumptions made by third-party code that uses them.

Comment: Why set a capacity of 0 ? by default, an empty list size is 0, right ?

Comment: @JavaDev: default is 10. capacity is preallocated space, as opposed to size, which is the number of elements in the list.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on usage, but I prefer the first option.

`private List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();`

The second option may have some benefits if your class is expected to recreate the ArrayList if the user of the class is able to set the `myList` variable to `null`. That would seem like bad practice to me though.