# Field vs field and new object

Tags: java, variables, object, field

I was wondering what is the diffrence between these two situations:

```
class Cell
{
    Messages msg;

    public void getMessage()
    {
        msg.getMessage();
    }
}
```

and:

```
class Cell
{
    Messages msg = new Messages();

    public void getMessage()
    {
        msg.getMessage();
    }
}
```

I know that in the first example I declared only field, and in the second I declared field, object and assigned object to the field. But in the both situations I can use `.getMessage()` method in `Cell` class, so what is diffrence and what should I use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the second case, the `Messages` member will be instantiated upon `Cell` instantiation. That means that `msg = new Messages()` will be called when you write `new Cell()` somewhere in your code.

In the first case, if you instantiate `Cell` (with `new Cell()` for instance) and call the `getMessage()` method without setting anything to `msg` first, you'll get a `NullPointerException` since the value of an object member is `null` by default. This will not be the case in the code you wrote in your second example.

Which solution you should use depends on what you want to do with your code. Both are acceptable and I fear this point is mainly opinion based. You can find more details on a similar question here: [Best practice for initializing an ArrayList field in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38124912/best-practice-for-initializing-an-arraylist-field-in-java).